# White blank pages in my react application after using the react-router-dom to link pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have been receiving white blank pages when trying to create multiple pages within my app and I have been using the `router-dom` to try and fix this but still can't understand why. Here is my code with `Home` and `Navigation` js being inside a components folder in the src directory and `App.js` just inside the src directory.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Glazing from './components/Glazing';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
     
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (      
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Navigation />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact/>
          <Route path="/glazing" component={Glazing}/>
        </div> 
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
     
export default App;
```

Nav.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
 
const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/glazing">Glazing</NavLink>
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default Navigation;
```

Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import logo from '../logo.svg';
import './Home.css';
import "@fontsource/dm-sans";

function home() {
  return (
    <div className="Home">
      <header className="Home-header">
        <h1>EPC RATING PREDICTOR</h1> 
      </header>
      <button> GET STARTED</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: which version of `react-router-dom` are you using?

Comment: 6.3.0 is the version i am using

Comment: you are not using switch from react router dom

Comment: and also it is replaced by Routes in v6

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `react-router-dom@6` then there are a couple things you need to address.

1. The `Switch` component was replaced by the [`Routes`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/routes) component and all `Route` components ***must*** be wrapped/rendered directly by `Routes`, or another `Route` component in the case of nesting routes.
2. The [`Route`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route) component API changed; gone are the `component`, and `render` and `children` function props, all replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, value.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
 
import Home from './components/Home';
import Glazing from './components/Glazing';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
 
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (      
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Navigation />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/glazing" element={<Glazing />} />
          </Routes>
        </div> 
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

See the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) guide for other changes.